# Logstash-plugin elasticsearch: apply executing searches in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Here is my excuting search to query my elasticsearch database (it works fine):

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/_search?pretty' -d '
{
"size":1,
"query": {
"match": {
"log.device":"xxxx"
}
},
"sort" : [ {
"_timestamp" :
{
"order":"desc"
}
}]
}'
```

I want to do the same thing through logstash with the plugin elasticsearch. However, there is no "size" option available in the website https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html

```
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["localhost:9200/test"]
query => "log.device:%{[log][device]}"
sort => "@timestamp:desc"
}
```

Do you how to manage this problem ?

Thank you for your attention and for your help.

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the size is [hardcoded to 1](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-elasticsearch/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/elasticsearch.rb#L91) in that plugin, you don't have to add any size parameter.

Also make sure to sort on `_timestamp` not `@timestamp`.

Finally, the `hosts` parameter doesn't take any index.

So:

```
elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
   query => "log.device:%{[log][device]}"
   sort => "_timestamp:desc"
}
```

If you really need to specify an index, this is not supported yet, but I've [created a PR](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-elasticsearch/pull/34) last week in order to support this. So until this gets merged and released, you'll be able to use my version instead of the official one:

```
$> git clone http://github.com/consulthys/logstash-filter-elasticsearch
$> cd logstash-filter-elasticsearch 
$> gem build logstash-filter-elasticsearch.gemspec
$> $LS_HOME/bin/plugin -install logstash-filter-elasticsearch-2.0.4.gem
```

After installing the amended plugin, you'll be able to work on a specific index:

```
elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
   index => "test"
   query => "log.device:%{[log][device]}"
   sort => "_timestamp:desc"
}
```

Comment: Val, i had a question about the size equl to 1. Since there are several documents in my elasticsearch with the same device name. Which document is returned in my query in the plugin elasticsearc within logstash ?

Comment: The one with the most recent timestamp according to your sort.

Comment: @Val Hi I have installed the `logstash-filter-elasticsearch-2.0.4.gem`. I am using `Logstash version 2.3.0`. When I try to include the `index` property in my `elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
   index => "aaaa"`. I am gettting error there is no such property called `index`. Am I missing anything.

Comment: @Mangoski Have you uninstalled the previous version of the filter first?

Comment: @Mangoski what do you see if you run this `bin/logstash-plugin list --verbose elasticsearch` ?

Comment: @Val when I run this I am getting this list `logstash-filter-elasticsearch (2.0.2)
logstash-input-elasticsearch (2.0.5)
logstash-output-elasticsearch (2.5.5)
logstash-output-elasticsearch-ec2 (2.0.4)
logstash-output-elasticsearch_http (2.0.4)
logstash-output-elasticsearch_java (2.1.3)`

Comment: See you have `logstash-filter-elasticsearch 2.0.2` and not `logstash-filter-elasticsearch 2.0.4`. You need to uninstall 2.0.2 first