# Logstash: error for querying elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

*Hello everyone,*

*Through logstash, I want to query elasticsearch in order to get fields from previous events and do some computation with fields of my current event and add new fields. Here is what I did:*

**input file:**

```
{"device":"device1","count":5}  
{"device":"device2","count":11} 
{"device":"device1","count":8}  
{"device":"device3","count":100}
{"device":"device3","count":95} 
{"device":"device3","count":155}
{"device":"device2","count":15} 
{"device":"device1","count":55}
```

**My expected output:**

```
{"device":"device1","count":5,"previousCount=0","delta":0}
{"device":"device2","count":11,"previousCount=0","delta":0}
{"device":"device1","count":8,"previousCount=5","delta":3}
{"device":"device3","count":100,"previousCount=0","delta":0}
{"device":"device3","count":95,"previousCount=100","delta":-5}
{"device":"device3","count":155,"previousCount=95","delta":60}
{"device":"device2","count":15,"previousCount=11","delta":4}
{"device":"device1","count":55,"previousCount=8","delta":47}
```

**Logstash filter part:**

```
filter {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200/device"]  
        query => 'device:"%{[device]}"'
        sort => "@timestamp:desc"
        fields => ['count','previousCount']
    } 
    if [previousCount]{
        ruby {
            code => "event[delta] = event[count] - event[previousCount]"
        }
    }
    else{
        mutate {
            add_field => { "previousCount" => "0" }
            add_field => { "delta" => "0" }
        }
    }
}
```

**My problem:**
*For every line of my input file I got the following error : Failed to query elasticsearch for previous event ..*
*It seems that every line completely treated is not put in elasticsearch before logstash starts to treat the next line.*

*I don't know if my conclusion is correct and, if yes, why it happens.*

*So, do you know how I could solve this problem please ?!*

*Thank you for your attention and your help.*

S

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810045/logstash-plugin-elasticsearch-apply-executing-searches-in-logstash/37811696#37811696

Comment: I followed this answer before asking :s ! I just wanted to complet the description, the error is:
error => NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Good. Do you have other indices in your cluster? If yes, you should try my forked version to be able to specify only the index you need to query.

Comment: I have others indexes. I have just used your forked version. But I still have the same error: Failed to query elasticsearch for previous event ... :error=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass>, :level=>:warn}
It is weird because I have documents in my index !

Comment: Oh I see the problem, the fields are not specified properly (documentation bug): replace `fields => ['count','previousCount']` by this `fields => {count => 'count' previousCount => 'previousCount'}`

Comment: Thanks val, I have no more this issue. However, Logstash sends requests to Elasticsearch in bulk and indexed events are not immediately made available for search in Elasticsearch. It seems to me that there will be a lag (up to a second or more) between an index passing through Logstash and it being searchable. I don't know how to solve this. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I think that's a different issue that's important enough to warrant a question of its own.